# Removing Columns from a Matrix in R when Any Value Is Greater, Equal or Less Than Threshold

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I'm playing with fictitious dice - two of them - and want to generate all the permutations possible to add up to a certain value, say *'9'*. So we have *{3,6}*, *{4,5}*, *{5,4}* and *{6,3}*. But I want to extend this, and I need some code.

If I wanted to know the permutations adding up to *'6'* instead, it could do:

```
library(partitions)
compositions(6, m = 2)

[1,] 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
[2,] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

This would give me almost what I need - we are tossing two dice, so there won't be any zeros possible... I'll come back to this later...

Unfortunately, when you go above *'6'*, you start getting compositions with numbers greater than '6', which are not found on the sides of a die. So I have to eliminate from the matrix returned by `compositions()` ANY columns with values greater than *'6'*. And yes, also any columns with zeros.

Can you help, perhaps applying the `all` or `any`, or subsetting with brackets, to come up with a short, elegant way of eliminating the unwanted columns in the case of *'9'* (or other examples > *6*):

```
compositions(9,2)

[1,] 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
[2,] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't make out your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the apply function like follows:

```
ans <- compositions(9, m = 2)
ans[,apply(ans,2,function(x) all(x<=6))]
```

with output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6    5    4    3
[2,]    3    4    5    6
```

---

Alternatively you can use `dplyr` which would look cleaner and might be more intuitive:

```
library(dplyr)
expand.grid(d1=1:6, d2=1:6) %>% filter(d1+d2 == 9)
```

output:

```
  d1 d2
1  6  3
2  5  4
3  4  5
4  3  6
```

Or using `ans` from above:

```
data.frame(as.matrix(t(ans))) %>% filter(X1 <= 6 & X2 <= 6)
```

Output:

```
  X1 X2
1  6  3
2  5  4
3  4  5
4  3  6
```

Comment: Nice! I wonder why you're not getting columns with zeros... Do you know?

Comment: because any of the columns with 0's will have the number with 9, which will then be excluded, since I used the all function so that all elements have to be less than 6.

Comment: I'm inserting the first solution inside a for loop, and I'm getting an error, saying that the object 'x' was not found. Do I necessarily have to use function(x)? Is this a problem?

Comment: @AntoniParellada Yes, you need `function(x)`. The whole third argument to `apply(,,)` constitutes a function. If you were using a pre-existing function, like taking the sum, you could simply write it's name: `apply(ans,2,sum)`. Passing an unnamed function as an argument as here is called using an "anonymous function."

Answer (score 2):

Constructing the correct set is cleaner than filtering the wrong set (as requested by the OP):

```
twodice <- function(x){d1 <- if (x>6) 6:(x-6) else 1:(x-1); rbind(d1,rev(d1))}
```

Examples:

```
> twodice(4)
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
d1    1    2    3
      3    2    1
> twodice(9)
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
d1    6    5    4    3
      3    4    5    6
```

Comment: Really nice... Thanks. Does rev(d1) simply return 'x'?

Comment: @AntoniParellada It reverses the vector from, e.g., 1,2,3 to 3,2,1. You can see the help page for a function by typing a question mark before its name, like `?rev`, in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm first checking if any value in columns contain any value greater than a threshold, and then see if there are any double FALSEs.

```
above.th <- apply(
    apply(x, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(m) m > 6),
    MARGIN = 2,
    any)
x[, !above.th]

And I get this result

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6    5    4    3
[2,]    3    4    5    6
```

Answer (score 0):

@chappers has a very nice, short solution, and I'll follow through crediting his answer. Practically at the same time, I got the following, which seems to work well, and is very similar:

```
a <- compositions(9,2)
a[,which(!apply(a, 2, function(x){any(x > 6) + any(x == 0)}))]

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6    5    4    3
[2,]    3    4    5    6
```